# RedirettoAction() doesn't takes object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following method

```
 public ActionResult APLogin(int userId, int courseId, string authToken)
    {
        try
        {
            //    // To be varified from Assessment platform, will be implemented later.
            //    //Make sure user/course exist in User/Course table
            //    //User should be enrolled in this course.
            //    //If anyone missing from all thee ..return false
            //    //Otherwise redirect to StaffHome page

            CourseRolesBOFilters courseRole = new CourseRolesBOFilters();
            courseRole.CourseId = courseId;
            courseRole.UserId = userId;

            return RedirectToAction("SelectCourse", courseRole, FormMethod.Post);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string errorMessage = string.Format("Error loading LMS page. Please try again or contact support.");
            Trace.WriteLine(errorMessage);
            Trace.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            ModelState.AddModelError("", String.Format("System failed to load LMS page. {0}", ex.Message));
            return View();
        }

    }
```

I am getting an error at line

```
return RedirectToAction("SelectCourse", courseRole, FormMethod.Post);
```

The error is:
`Argument 2: cannot convert from 'BrightScribeDAL.NonDBBO.CourseRolesBOFilters' to 'string'`[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyTUV.png)

Can anyone please help

Comment: You should clarify what about the error message you don't understand. It is pretty clear in what your problem is... For example why do you think you should be able to pass an object of type `CourseRolesBOFilters` there?

Comment: @Chris if i convert courseRole into string and store it into a string variable then will it make sense?

Comment: Probably not. What you want to do is look at what the method is actually expecting and pass that. Paul's answer says exactly that and has links to the documentation. If the courseRole when converted to a string is the name of your controller then it would make sense. I'm guessing that isn't the case though....

Comment: It need to be `return RedirectToAction("SelectCourse", courseRole);` assuming its in the same controller, but it will only work if the model contains simple value properties (it will fail if the model contains properties which are complex objects or collections)

Comment: @StephenMuecke it is in the same controller and yes it has value properties

Comment: Then `return RedirectToAction("SelectCourse", courseRole);` will work fine (although I'm confused why you have `FormMethod.Post` in your attempt - are you attempting to redirect to a POST method - which is not possible)

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at Microsoft documentation about `RedirectToAction` found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.118).aspx
You are sending three parameters to the function, and by looking at the documentation, the only two signatures that has 3 parameters are:

> RedirectToAction(String, String, Object)
>   RedirectToAction(String, String, RouteValueDictionary)

Both requires second parameter to be string, hence your error shown in the image you posted `Cannot convert from 'xyz' to 'string'`
Make sure to send the correct parameters, and you'll be okay.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I hope the below table itself will  solve all your problem and doubts.
[image]

For your current problem , fifth row in table will be helpful that is,

```
RedirectToAction(string actionName,string controllerName,object routeValue)
```

Your Ex:

```
return RedirectToAction("SelectCourse", "AnycontrollerName", new{CourseID = courseId,...(you can pass anyno of route values) });
```

**Useful Link:**http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/3116/to-understand-various-types-of-redirecttoaction-override-methods-in-as

Hope above information was helpful

Thanks

Karthik